# Generate random value from gamma distribution in Java

Tags: java, random, gamma-distribution

How do I generate numbers from a gamma distribution in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`GammaDistribution`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/GammaDistribution.html) from Apache Commons-Math package:

```
double sample = new GammaDistribution(shape, scale).sample();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility in the Apache Commons Math 3.3 API

```
GammaDistribution(double shape, double scale)
// Creates a new gamma distribution with specified values of the shape and scale parameters.
GammaDistribution(double shape, double scale, double inverseCumAccuracy)
// Creates a new gamma distribution with specified values of the shape and scale parameters.
GammaDistribution(RandomGenerator rng, double shape, double scale)
// Creates a Gamma distribution.
GammaDistribution(RandomGenerator rng, double shape, double scale, double inverseCumAccuracy)
// Creates a Gamma distribution.
```

Reference: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/GammaDistribution.html

Comment: Thank you very much for replying I am very new to java I think I should download Apache Commons Math 3.3 API and then add it to the path in eclipse is this right

Comment: Yes, that's right! Add the library to the build path, afterwards you can use it in your program!

Comment: I obtained the answer thank you

Comment: Sorry but I get the solution from him he explain how to do it in java I have to be fair I apologies again sorry

Comment: what about inverse gamma? Can this Apache commons math lib do that?